# In Kettle, is it possible to include the name of the XML files in the output

Tags: pentaho, kettle, spoon

In Pentaho Kettle I have set up "Get data from XML" that extracts data from all *.xml files in a given directory.

Is it possible to include the name of the XML files in the output so that I would be able to tell which XML file the extracted data came from.

Something like the screenshot below
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Get XML Data step you can define a filename field on the Aditional fields tab.